# System could not be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class problem6
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  System.out.println("Please enter an integer:");

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  int number = keyboard.nextInt( );

  if (number >= 100) ll (number >= 50 && number <= 75)
  System.out.println("YES"); //here is the error
  else
   System.out.println("NO");
 }


 private static Object ll(boolean b) {
  return null;
 }

}

​
```

I don't understand why but eclipse made me insert "private static object...in order to use the "or" (ll) in my program

Comment: Did you mean `||` (as in 'or')  right above your error?

Comment: Yes I meant to say "or" in java language.

Comment: What's the point of this program? Is it supposed to print 'YES' if the number is above 100 `OR` the number is between 50 and 75?

Comment: Yes that is the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System` wasn't being recognized because your syntax was incorrect. The below code shows you what I think you're trying to get at.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class problem6
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer:");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = keyboard.nextInt( );

        if ((number >= 100) || (number >= 50 && number <= 75)){
            System.out.println("YES");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

The boolean comparator `||` isn't two lowercase Ls, it's two pipes. That's why Java wasn't happy with what you had written. Furthermore, you defined a double-Ld method in your original code (I think you thought it was the `||`) so your code was trying to be compiled (in English) as...

```
if the number is greater than or equal to 100 <method call with a boolean argument> print "Yes"
```

To java, that makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Cool. If it helped you vote according to community policy.

Comment: one more question, how would I input the pipes using my laptops keyboard?

Comment: The 'pipe' character is (should be) directly above your `Return` (or `Enter`) key. As a side note, generally you should keep follow-up questions limited to *the original question* at hand. It defeats the purpose of the site to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (number >= 100) ll (number >= 50 && number <= 75)
```

should be using the 'or' operator `||` rather than the double-ell `ll`.

In addition, you need to put parentheses around the entire `if` expression since that's required as well:

```
if ((number >= 100) || (number >= 50 && number <= 75))
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error will appear if you have incomplete code somewhere. So please thoroughly check the code to get rid of this problem.